# when we will use Bean rather than normal class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, javabeans

Actually what is the major difference between Bean and Java Normal Class and what time we will be using Bean into the Project rather than Normal Class
Please help me out

Comment: I Know those Difference already referred but my question when we will be using Bean rather than Java Class please check the Question Properly before Down voting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Bean is a data structure.  For example you may have a person:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private int age;
}
```

It is a structure for storing information.